# Powershell - output organisation name when if statement is true

Tags: powershell, if-statement, exchange-server-2010

I am making changes to an Exchange 2010 platform, see below...

```
foreach ($org in get-organization)
{

Remove-ManagementRoleAssignment -identity "$org\Mail Recipients-Recipient Management" -confirm:$false
Remove-ManagementRoleAssignment -identity "$org\Mail Recipients-Organization Management" -confirm:$false
New-ManagementRole -Parent "mail recipients" -name "Restricted Mail Recipients" -Organization "$org"
set-ManagementRoleEntry -Identity "$org\Restricted Mail Recipients\Set-mailbox" -parameters "emailaddresses" -RemoveParameter -confirm:$false
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -name "Restricted Mail Recipients-organization management" -Role "Restricted Mail Recipients" -SecurityGroup "organization management" -Organization "$org"
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -name "Restricted Mail Recipients-organization management-delegating" -Role "Restricted Mail Recipients" -SecurityGroup "organization management" -Organization "$org" -Delegating:$true
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -name "Restricted Mail Recipients-recipient management" -Role "Restricted Mail Recipients" -SecurityGroup "recipient management" -Organization "$org"
}
```

I have test this against a test organisation and I am happy with it

As part of the testing process I wish to run the following script to display all the organisations that have the new management role "Restricted Mail Recipients". see below...

```
foreach ($org in get-organization)
{
$man_role = get-ManagementRoleEntry -Identity "$org\Restricted Mail Recipients\Set-mailbox"
if ($man_role.emailaddresses)
{
Write-host $org
}
}
```

When I run the script I get an error message about throttling but the test organisation that I changed isn't displayed

Ideally I would like to have the changed organisations displayed so I can confirm my change has been applied

Any help is appreciated, thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit that I'm a little confused and maybe this is just a typo - but I am unaware of a `Get-Organization` command.  The closest thing that I am aware of is `Get-OrganzationConfig`.

I'm also a bit confused about how your first script worked for removing and adding the role assignments.  The `$org` variable should hold an object, containing various properties about the organization.  To get the name out of this object, it would be `$org.Name`.

So that should also be the answer to your question.  Instead of `$org`, you should use `$org.Name` to output the name of the organization.